# Centralized SecurityContext injection in jax-rs

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I have RESTful web services, implemented using Jax-RS. I need to use `SecurityContext.getUserPrincipal().getName()` to get the name of the current user.

I have a lot of web service methods and for every method I'm injecting `SecurityContext` using `@Context` annotation. The problem is I need to do so for every web service method that I have:

For example:

```
@GET
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response getSomething(@Context SecurityContext context) {
        CmdUtils.buildCmd(CmdGetSomething.class, context, getUserPrincipal())
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

And inside `CmdUtils.buildCmd` method I get the user with `UserPrincipal.getName()`. Btw, `buildCmd` method is generic and is the same for every REST method. So I centralized username handling.

However, I still need to inject `SecurityContext` for every REST method using `@Context` annotation as a parameter for every RETS method.

Is there a way to centralize this?

Comment: It's not clear what you are actually trying to achieve. The answer could be yes or it could be no. There's not enough context. One thing to note though is that it also be injected as a field or through the constructor, so one injection per class. You could also use a filter, but again, there is not enough context to say whether this will work for you or not.

Comment: you could try to inject it as an instance variable. so instead of having it as a method param - put it once in your class like `@Context SecurityContext context`.